# HTML and PHP issue in Select Dropdown

Tags: php, html

Hello am having a dropdown box like the below one,

```
function dropdown( $name, array $options, $selected=null )
{
/*** begin the select ***/
$dropdown = '<select name="'.$name.'" id="'.$name.'">'."\n";

$selected = $selected;
/*** loop over the options ***/
foreach( $options as $key=>$option )
{
    /*** assign a selected value ***/
    $select = $selected==$key ? ' selected' : null;

    /*** add each option to the dropdown ***/
    $dropdown .= '<option value="'.$key.'"'.$select.'>'.$option.'</option>'."\n";
}

/*** close the select ***/
$dropdown .= '</select>'."\n";

/*** and return the completed dropdown ***/
return $dropdown;
}
?>

<form>

<?php
$name = 'my_dropdown';
$options = array( 'dingo', 'wombat', 'kangaroo' );
$selected = 1;

echo dropdown( $name, $options, $selected );

?>
</form>
```

after running this code, everything is showing correctly, but the selected option is incorrect by changing the value of selected.

The problem is, its showing like this
        `<option value="1" selected="">wombat</option>`

but actually it should show like this
    `<option value="1" selected>wombat</option>`

Kindly suggest me how to solve this issue

Comment: That's not a problem. That's just browser representation of a property. What is exactly wrong - what value **should be** selected and what **is** selected?

Comment: `$selected = $selected;` — This doesn't make sense. And I should replace `: null` by `: ''`.

Comment: Actually its not selecting the correct value because, selected="" is showing in the code and wrongly displaying the values. Please run the above program by changing the value of $selected to 0 or 2. Then you know the exact issue

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers use `selected=true` , some just `selected`.
Using both is fine too.
So don't check it in Firebug or something, because that might be something else then what is the actual code.
Try

```
$select = $selected==$key ? ' selected="true" selected' :  "";
```

ps. you can leave out `$selected = $selected;`